# bootable USB flash drive not recognized (found) by bios on USB3.0 ports but found on USB2.0 port

Tags: boot, usb, bios, flash

As the title says, when i plug mu **USB Kingston HyperX** 64GB USB flash drive into USB3.0 ports on my **Lenovo Y50** it doesn't show up in the BIOS boot menu (it does sometimes, but so rarely and randomly), but on USB2.0 port it shows up every time.

EDIT: it is not partiton scheme or filesystem related. The ports work fine under Windows OS. Upon even further investigation. OS or no OS, BIOS is not recognizing the USB. On the rare instance it does recognize it, the USB LED light shines but that is a random and rare scenario.
Tried GPT and MBR no difference, legacy turned on in BIOS  but will try turning it off to see if it helps.

Might just be what KJ4IPS said... still looking for a solution or an explanation.

Comment: Does it the same thing when plugged under Windows OS, or Linux (or whatever your OS is)?

Comment: under Windows OS everything works as expected

Comment: So you've said it's not a partition scheme issue, but have you tried creating the bootable USB using a GPT partition scheme JUST to see if its recognized as a bootable media? I know in my newer Spectres, I can only boot MBR if I choose Legacy mode which would be fine but it trips up bitlocker every time on reboot. The only way the bios will recognize my USB without turning on Legacy mode is if I use a GPT partition scheme when I create the bootable media. It's not an answer to your problem, but you didn't mention trying GPT with Rufus so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: tried GPT and MBR no difference, legacy turned on but will try turning it off to see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that the USB3 controller and drive are not always both ready by the time the system gathers the list of bootable devices. Many systems allow a configurable delay before continuing boot to compensate for this delay.

Comment: Sounds perfectly reasonable with above given explanation of the problem BUT upon further investigation, USB on the "problematic" port was recognized every time while it was not bootable (no OS just a .mkv file), but when made into a bootable USB via Rufus (MBR for both UEFI and Legacy) it stops being recognized, as if it is recognized but intentionally left out of the boot list. I wil try now different Partition schemes and File systems to see if there is a pattern and EDIT the initial explanation.