# Ubuntu in external HDD not recognized as boot option when plugged in USB 3.0 port

Tags: hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive, usb-3, usb-2

I found this [**similar question**](https://superuser.com/questions/1228531/bootable-usb-flash-drive-not-recognized-found-by-bios-on-usb3-0-ports-but-foun) yet unsolved.
I've installed Kubuntu 20.04 on an external HDD, with Grub boot menu, configured for EFI (I'm not sure about this one). The exHDD is a USB3.0 HDD case/box. When connecting to USB 2.0 port, it shows up in the boot option list but doesn't when connecting to USB 3.0 port.
I've tried on several PC:

- My laptop, Lenovo G510, is described above. However, there are 1 or 2 times it does bootable with USB 3.0 but never seen again.
- PC1, MSI motherboard, boot fine with both USB 2.0 and 3.0.
- PC2, Aorus motherboard, only boot with USB 2.0.
- My school's PCs, boot fine with both USB 2.0 and 3.0/3.1.

Boot with USB 2.0 noticeably reduces performance. The main purpose of that exHDD is being my portable Linux system.
What causes this and can this issue be fixed or I must live with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some mainboards do not boot from USB3.0 ports. The ability to boot from USB3.0 is a test criterion of my preferred computer journal. Technically this is a firmware issue and can be fixed by a bios update but your mainboard manufacturer will not waste money on such issues.